# Lagrangian with Higher Order derivatives and Ignorable coordinate

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism

I have a Lagrangian for a physical system that ends up being function of one generalized coordinate $q_1$, its generalized velocity $\dot{q}_1$ and its generalized (?) accelration $\ddot{q}_1$, and function of the generalized velocity $\dot{q}_2$ and (?) generalized acceleration $\ddot{q}_2$. I have not encountered how one could classify such lagrangians (higher order perhaps but no dependence on $q_2$?). The physical system is an electrical circuit if that helps.

$$ L(q_1,\dot{q}_1, \ddot{q}_1,\dot{q}_2,\ddot{q}_2) $$

I'm trying to classify this lagrangian in all possible classifications of order and constraints, and also try to deduce if I can transform to a Hamiltonian or even a Routhian.

Does anyone know what kind of lagrangian this is and is it even reasonable to have dependence on higher order derivatives but not the original coordinate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about a specific 2nd-order Lagrangian? Which? In order to receive useful advice, you would probably have to be more explicit.

Comment: No it is not a specific one but a class that has that form for some electrical circuits I am considering. I am unable to find classifications of lagrangians with higher orders and degeneracy/nondegeneracy classifications w.r.t. to variables.